# find the GPS coordinates of all road intersections in shape file

Tags: mysql, gis, shapefile

I imported shape file to mysql. I found in shape file, a line(road) has many points on it, but these points are not exactly intersections. I am now extracting the road network from shape file so I really need to know the GPS coordinates of each intersection. How can I get that?

Comment: Try to describe better your data. I.e. how much points have your lines? What do you mean exactly with  _' but these points are not exactly intersections'_ ? Post the result of the query `SELECT DISTINCT ST_NumPoints(shape) FROM your_table` and `SELECT ST_AsText(shape) FROM your_table LIMIT 3;` Do you need only the coordinates where two or more lines intersects?

Comment: Yes, I need only the coordinates where two or more lines intersects.Sorry for the confusion.                                    | LINESTRING(-83.88845 35.989085,-83.88867 35.989199,-83.889333 35.989541,-83.88
9554 35.989656,-83.889788 35.989777,-83.890492 35.990141,-83.890727 35.990263,-8
3.890961 35.99038,-83.89154 35.990672,-83.891662 35.990738,-83.891893 35.990863,
-83.892088 35.990965,-83.892471 35.991167,-83.892677 35.991271,-83.892875 35.991
371)

Comment: Above is the result of the second query (i changed it to limit 1). this is part of the result of query one. It has 270 rows in total.   some lines have more than 500 points on it.                  +---------------------+
| ST_NumPoints(shape) |
+---------------------+
|                  15 |
|                  10 |
|                  45 |
|                   6 |
|                  24 |
|                   4 |

Comment: I tried to search the locations of the points and found that they are just a point on a road, it could be in the middle of two intersections. I really want to extract all the intersections.

Comment: thanks. Better you add this additional informations in the question (not in comments)